# Using the \newarrow command from Taylor's commutative diagrams package

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I want to define new arrows to use in a commutative diagram, but I just can't make it work. The documentation is not particularly helpful; it doesn't even tell you where to put the

```
\newarrow{Name}{tail}{filler}{middle}{filler}{head}
```

bit for example. Even when TeX stops complaining about how I've defined the arrow, it won't use it; the undefined control sequence error comes up whenever I try and use the arrow. The error message suggests using the PostScript Option, but that also doesn't work. Any ideas?

(For now, I'll try and use a different diagrams tool, but I'd really like to know how to get this to work.) Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit: After doing what Stefan's answer suggested, I'm now trying

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
(other packages)
\usepackage[small,nohug]{diagrams}
\diagramstyle[labelstyle=\scriptstyle]
\newarrowtail{-}
\newarrowead{-}
\newarrow{Dots}{-}...{-}
(other pramle etc)
\begin{document}
(blah)
\begin{diagram}
A & \rDots & B
\end{diagram}
(blah)
\end{document}
```

which works (in so much as TeX now produces the desired diagrams), but now it says:

LaTeX Error: missing \begin{document} ...
\newarrow{Dots}{-}
                  ...{-}

So presumably is has a problem with the arrowhead being a -? How to fix that?

(I'm trying to get an arrow looking something like - \cdots - to intidacate an infinite line (currently it just looks like \cdots, but that's fine I suppose).

Comment: Welcome to {TeX}! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Here's a link to the package: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/taylor/

Comment: The command works fine for me - you can put it everywhere as long as you declare the arrow before you use it in a diagram. I suspect it's a very specific problem - which programs do you use in order to compile your input file (`latex`,`pdflatex`,`dvips`,...)?

Comment: The problem is caused by `\newarrowhead` and `\newarrowtail`. It seems that they take hidden arguments, such as `\newarrowhead{triangle}\rhtriangle\lhtriangle\dhtriangle\uhtriangle`. I would not use a package with unusual syntax and incomplete documentation.

Comment: Right, I'll just use \newarrow{Dots}{.}{.}{.}{.}{.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a minimal example. It defines an arrow called `SuperArrow`. It uses the arrow to the right by putting `\r` right before the arrow name.

Global definitions should be done in the preamble, after the required package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\newarrow{SuperArrow}{>>}...{>>}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$A \rTo^{\text{ very long arrow }} B$

$A \rSuperArrow^{\text{ very long arrow }} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: you should correctly install the package. It's published as `diagrams.tex`, download it, save it into your texmf tree or besides your document and load it by `\input{diagrams}`, or rename it to `diagrams.sty` and load it by `\usepackage{diagrams}`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Your example certainly works, but when I put my arrow definition after \usepackage{diagrams}, TeX complains that \begin{document} is missing (even though it still produces the arrow as I'd like it to). @diabonas: I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: @user4190: your comment is incomplete, perhaps you pressed the enter key too early. You could edit it or post a new comment.

Comment: (yes, I just wanted to start a new line - shift + enter?)

Comment: @David K: you could edit your question to add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), like I did in my answer, that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Kottwitz: I have edited my original question as requested.